# Rscript.exe cannot open/read scripts, permission denied

Tags: r, cmd, rscript

So I'm trying to run some R scripts via cmd directly using

```
Rscript.exe "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\test.R"
```

but it fails every time with the same error :

```
Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\test.R': Permission denied
```

However, if I run it via

```
R CMD BATCH "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\test.R"
```

Then it works. Do you know why Rscript cannot reach the file ? I would really like to use this rather the R CMD BATCH approach.
Everything is in the PATH and I tried moving the .R script file around to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Rscript --help` run fine?

Comment: Yes, seems like it does.

Comment: in fact, I can run commands like `Rscript -e rnorm(1)` and it will work with no issue. It just looks like it cannot open a file.